# `LOAD_FAST` in dis module

Tags: python

In [32.12. dis — Disassembler for Python bytecode — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html), there's an example saying:

Example: Given the function myfunc():

```
def myfunc(alist):
    return len(alist)
```

the following command can be used to display the disassembly of myfunc():

```
>>> dis.dis(myfunc)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (alist)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

I can understand `LOAD_GLOBAL` `CALL_FUNCTION` and `RETURN_VALUE`

What's the meaning of `LOAD_FAST`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python dis docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html):

> LOAD_FAST(var_num)
>
> Pushes a reference to the local co_varnames[var_num] onto the stack.

So, in your case, the LOAD_FAST instruction loads `alist` to be able to pass it to the global `len` function:

```
return        len          (alist)

RETURN_VALUE  LOAD_GLOBAL  LOAD_FAST
                < CALL_FUNCTION >
```